# Jquery scrollTop will only scroll to first id and not the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sticky bar that I am using so that the users can click a link and scroll to that particular part of the page. The only issue is that it will only scroll to the first element. If you click another link it kind of creeps down slowly but doesn't actually move at all.

Here is what it is doing: http://jsfiddle.net/jcdevelopment/bEcUy/

Here is the call I make, does anyone see anything wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    jQuery("#notinmas").click(function (){
                //$(this).animate(function(){
                    jQuery('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: jQuery("#notinmasb").offset().top
                    }, 2000);
                //});
            });
        });
```

Comment: log the elements offset, and you'll see that it's not returning what you think it's returning.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this forked fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qDB4R/4/
I added non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;` to your anchor tags further down in the markup.  I also cleaned up the jQuery some since you only need one document.ready.

Comment: I think I may be too new to JSFiddle but I do not see your updates when I go to that link. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/j7xBs/)**</kbd>

You had multiple id's, so replace anchor id's with HTML5 data attribute e.g. `data-id`

***Note:** Having multiple id's is invalid (use `class` instead) and in your case cause links to animate to themselves.

```
<div class="stickyEditorD">
  <a data-id="notinmas">SKUs Not in MAS</a>| 
  <a data-id="subnotinhouse">Substrates not in-house</a>|
  <a data-id="notverinmas">Not verified with MAS</a>|
  <a data-id="openorders">Open order items</a>|
  <a data-id="shipped">Shipped orders</a>| 
  <a data-id="giftcardhis">Gift Card history</a>|
  <a data-id="os_jobs">OS jobs</a>|
  <a data-id="ezquotes_p">EZ quotes Production</a>|
  <a data-id="ezquotes_f">EZ quotes Fulfillment</a>
</div>
```

and instead of putting empty anchor with id e.g `<a id="notinmasb"></a>` as target, you can put id in `.box` div e.g. `<div id="notinmasb" class="box">` it's more precise.

---

and use this script instead of writing separate script for every anchor. (jQuery write less do more)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".stickyEditorD a").click(function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery("#"+$(this).data('id')).offset().top }, 2000);
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I noticed that I did not change the ID names and I went ahead and went with the data-id. Works great. Thanks you.

Comment: Also a basic question. Since I have a sticky bar, it tends to overlap the header on my div. Covering up the title of that table. Is there a way I can set the location to be about 15px before its placement? Tried with offset(), but did not work. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, I was almost there, but I was adding that to the offset() instead of the top(). Works great, thanks for the help!